# I am having a problem with a Syntax error with a Filter command in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Private Sub CboQuickSearch_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Filter = "Item Card Number = " & Me.CboQuickSearch.Value"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the dangling `"` after `Me.CboQuickSearch.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a text value in single quotes:

```
Me.Filter = "Item Card Number = '" & Me.CboQuickSearch.Value & "'"
```